# Detect specific inheritor in function call

Tags: c++, inheritance, smart-pointers

I have base class:

```
class Expression {
public:
    // ...
};

using ExpressionPtr = std::shared_ptr<Expression>;
```

and derived class from it:

```
class Const_operation : public Expression {
public:
    // ...
};
class Non_const_operation : public Expression {
public:
    // ...
};
```

My question is how to make overloaded function for specific derived class?

```
// Regular case

ExpressionPtr Sum(ExpressionPtr value) {
  return std::make_shared<Const_operation>(std::move(value));
}

// My unsuccessful attempt to dispatch only for Non_const_operation

template <typename _Ptr, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<
  std::shared_ptr<Non_const_operation>, std::decay_t<_Ptr>>>>
ExpressionPtr Sum(_Ptr value) {
  return std::make_shared<Non_const_operation>(std::move(value));
}
```

Comment: return std::make_shared<Const_operation>(std::move(value)); this is fishy as well: what are you trying to do? your constructors are taking shared_ptr as well?

Comment: This would typically be done with virtual functions in `Expression`. The overrides in the derived classes would implement the type specific operations.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to specialize behavior for part of an inheritance tree is `dynamic_cast`. When you have `shared_ptr` in the mix, that means `dynamic_pointer_cast`:

```
ExpressionPtr Sum(ExpressionPtr value) {
  if (auto non_const_value = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Non_const_operation>(value))
    // do the non-const thing
  else
    // do the const thing
  }
```

Comment: Yes, my problem solved by adding `bool` class member and assigning to it dynamic cast result. Thank you.